# Python regex removing string from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list of dictionaries

```
d =
[
    {
        "Business": "Company A",
        "Category": "Supply Chain",
        "Date": "Posted Date\nDecember 21 2021",
    },
    {
        "Business": "Company B",
        "Category": "Manufacturing",
        "Date": "Posted Date\nDecember 21 2021",
    }
]
```

I'm trying to use `re` to remove the `Posted Date\n` string from the dictionaries but getting the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

My code is the following:

```
regex = re.compile('Posted Date\n')
filtered = [i for i in d if not regex.match(i)]
print(filtered)
```

If I do the same on a normal list of strings with no dictionaries it's working. Would I have to convert my dictionaries into strings first?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that `i` doesn't refer to what you think it refers to.

Comment: `i` is each dictionary within your list, hence the error

Comment: and maybe just go for [`removeprefix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix), no need for `re`...

Comment: Do you really need regex to do this ? Can't you do normal string search with `startswith` and remove if found ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `d` is the list of dictionaries, then you're looping over the dictionaries themselves. So for the first iteration:

```
i = {
    "Business": "Company A",
    "Category": "Supply Chain",
    "Date": "Posted Date\nDecember 21 2021",
}
```

And indeed, you cannot use regex on a dictionary. You would need to go deeper and loop over the key and values in the dictionary. But that can also cause RunTimeErrors if you're changing the dictionary while looping.

```
import re

d = [{
    "Business": "Company A",
    "Category": "Supply Chain",
    "Date": "Posted Date\nDecember 21 2021",
}, {
    "Business": "Company B",
    "Category": "Manufacturing",
    "Date": "Posted Date\nDecember 21 2021",
}]

regex = re.compile('Posted Date\n')

for dikt in d:
    for key, value in list(dikt.items()):  # make a list to prevent RuntimeError
        if regex.match(value): 
            del dikt[key]
```

This would omit the `Date` key entirely:

```
d = [{
    "Business": "Company A",
    "Category": "Supply Chain",
}, {
    "Business": "Company B",
    "Category": "Manufacturing",
}]
```

If you just want to get rid of the "Posted Date\n", this suffices:

```
d = [{
    "Business": "Company A",
    "Category": "Supply Chain",
    "Date": "Posted Date\nDecember 21 2021",
}, {
    "Business": "Company B",
    "Category": "Manufacturing",
    "Date": "Posted Date\nDecember 21 2021",
}]


for dikt in d:
    for key, value in dikt.items():
        dikt[key] = value.replace('Posted Date\n', '') # replace string from all our values stupidly :)
```

Result:

```
d = [{
    "Business": "Company A",
    "Category": "Supply Chain",
    "Date": "December 21 2021",
}, {
    "Business": "Company B",
    "Category": "Manufacturing",
    "Date": "December 21 2021",
}]
```

Comment: I've gone with your last suggestion, worked great thanks! Yes, d was my list of dicts.